# Multiple domains into wget --accept-regex?

Tags: wget

I want to download, recursively, the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page, but only the files from upload.wikimedia.org and de.wikipedia.org

It works by using these commands:

```
wget -H -r -l1 --accept-regex upload.wikimedia.org https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
wget -H -r -l1 --accept-regex de.wikipedia.org https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

My question is: is it possible to combine two domains in a single command? Something like this:

```
wget -H -r -l1 --accept-regex de.wikipedia.org||upload.wikimedia.org https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

where "||" means "OR"

Comment: Have you searched the regex syntax descriptions?

Comment: yes, I did that. Wget does not accept "\|", as grep or sed accepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `--accept-regex` uses the POSIX [*Extended Regular Expression*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) syntax, where a *single* `|` is used for alternative branches. (The same applies if you tell wget to use PCRE syntax, which is a superset of POSIX ERE.)

Note that POSIX *Extended* regexp syntax (used by `egrep` or `sed -E`) is different from the POSIX *Basic* regexp syntax (used by `grep` or `sed`). For example, BRE uses `\|` for alternative branches and `|` for a literal pipe symbol, but ERE does the exact opposite. The same goes for parentheses and many other special characters which have to be backslash-prefixed in BRE but not in ERE.

In any case the regexp would look like this:

- `de.wikipedia.org|upload.wikimedia.org`

  `(de|upload).wikimedia.org`
- More correct (dots are special in regex syntax as well):

  `de\.wikipedia\.org|upload\.wikimedia\.org`

  `(de|upload)\.wikimedia\.org`

Note that the `|` character is special in most interactive shells (it is the *pipe* operator), so any parameter containing it needs to be quoted:

```
wget --accept-regex "(de|upload).wikimedia.org"
```

Comment: It works, thank you. 'wget -Hr -l1 --accept-regex "(de.wikipedia|upload.wikimedia).org" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page' - the double quotes did the trick.